# Will a satellite escape from the bounds of Earth's gravity if its orbital velocity is increased to escape velocity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, satellites

If orbital velocity $(v=\omega r)$ is increased to escape velocity at that certain orbit, will it move to infinity? I know that it will skid from that orbit as vehicles do when their velocity is more than the equivalent velocity of banking of road. But this satellite has been revolving, shouldn't it just move to another orbit and revolve instead of moving to infinity since gravity is still effective on it?

Comment: You seem to be confusing 'rotate' with 'revolve.'    In addition, you may have forgotten that velocity is a vector, and the direction does matter.

Comment: Ohh I noticed it now that I meant "revolve" but wrote "rotate" instead.

Comment: To really answer the question, you have to solve a differential equation. I'm too lazy to re-learn that, but I can at least tell you this: _Escape velocity_ is not a fixed value. It is a _function_ of the distance between two bodies. It falls off as the bodies get further apart. Gravitational attraction extends to infinity, but if two bodies are separating at greater-than-escape velocity, then even as their velocity slows down (because of the gravitational attraction), it will always stay ahead of the local "escape" velocity, and it never will reach zero.

Comment: If two bodies separate at less-than-escape velocity, then the separation value always will be less than the local escape velocity, eventually it will reach zero, and then the bodies will start to fall back toward each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the speed will increase the orbit. At some point the speed corresponds to an infinitely large orbit, meaning that the object will never return. This is called **escape velocity**.

So, per definition, if an object such as a satellite - initially in orbit or stationary, that doesn't matter - reaches escape velocity, then it will *not* just reach a higher orbit but will never come back. By definition. If it *did* come back and just reached a higher orbit, then we wouldn't have called it escape velocity in the first place.

And to the note on gravity, be aware that gravity *always* acts on an object. Also on objects that move with escape velocity. The velocity is just large enough to outweigh the effect of gravity continuously.

Comment: Lets say that the orbital velocity of the object is 5km/s and escape velocity is 11km/s,  if we increase the orbital velocity of the object by 6km/s how is it going to infinite distance? I mean if I had thrown the same object from that point straight away (perpendicular) from the parallel line to earth surface with 11km/s then that would have made sense to me but the object is rotating an we are increasung the velocity in a direction parallel to the surface so shouldn't that make the object rotate in an orbit at a finute distance?

Comment: I am considering that the gravity wil force it to bend as much as possible to make its trajectory circular. But incase of throwing the trajectory becomes parabolic as far as I know

Comment: @MSKB Yes, it becomes parabolic, and it never comes back down. It just keeps going up.

Comment: As players of Kerbal Space Program will know ;) the position is fixed for the moment, but the opposite point in the orbit will go further and further up, until eventually it's not a bound orbit any more, but a parabolic one, at which point the object is on an escape trajectory

Comment: What about my first comment?

Comment: Btw is that parabolic trajectory is with respect to an observer on earth or is it with respect to space?

Comment: It's going out on a parabolic orbit, with the space probe at its tip (assuming instantaneous acceleration)

Comment: @MSKB To your first comment, it sounds like you are asking to the *direction* of the escape velocity. If we shoot a rocket with escape velocity *perpendicular* upwards from the ground, then shouldn't it give a different result than if it was sent off *parallel* to the ground? It may seem intuitive, but is actually wrong. It will not make a difference. As long as the object doesn't hit anything on its path, then the kinetic energy carried when it has escape velocity is enough to break out of the gravitational energy well that gravity causes.

Comment: Ohh now I get it

Comment: @Steeven just to be a pain, I don't think that is true for a  "flat earth" of infinite extent.  The reason it works is that after a few hundred km or so, the velocity vector relative to a finite 3-D body  is close enough to perpendicular as not to make any difference.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I very much agree, sir. Thank you for being a pain. My answer does indeed not try to assume a flat earth, a model for which escape velocity would be directional fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

If the satellite's new direction is such that it does not crash into Earth or feels friction from its atmosphere it will move to infinity.

The escape velocity 'at that orbit' meaning at that height is such that $$v^2/2 = GM_E/(R_E+h) \,.$$. This means that the binding energy, total energy excluding rest energies of satellite and Earth, vanishes if the satellite is boosted to escape speed. From then on it is an unbound system and dissociation will occur.